# Pushing commits to multiple repos

Tags: git

Lets say i am working on directory `/Users/UserName/Documents/Repos/ProjectX`. After each successful feature complete, I `comit` my changes. Now what I want to is to push these changes to multiple repos. Can i do this under git ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pull/push from multiple remote locations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a remote for each repository you want to push to.

Define a remote using this form:

```
git remote add repo1 <url>
```

For example, if pushing to the [Linux Kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git) the `remote` command would look like this:

```
git remote add repo1 https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
```

Then, when you push, explicitly reference that remote:

```
git push repo1 master
```

Learn more about managing remotes [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes).